# What to do after system restore does not work?

Tags: windows-vista, bsod, system-restore

Sometimes after a windows update I get a blue SOD on start-up, and normally resolve this by going into safe mode, system restore, check problem with update / reinstall all fine.

On this occasion I updated windows, failed to restart immediately laptop was on for approx 2 days, had blue SOD on start up just after the mouse curser appeared, but unable to use system restore as it had been over written by 4 other system restore points.

This was 4 days ago, so far I have tried:-
Researching BSOD error codes, these are mostly 19's but occasionally get others 5, C5, 50 and 1A. Information was all very general and nothing that was really relevant.

windows updates in uninstall the latest one is showing as the 12/04/14 and i'm sure I've had others since then, and certainly the 01/04/2014 one which has cause all this. researched how to show all updates in safe mode to no avail.

Researched BSOD and correction.

Tried updating all drivers, this did not work

A microsoft clean boot does not fix issue

Tried upgrading to Windows 7, but this tells me that this cannot be done in safe mode or full install with format of hard drive, and just too many programs to re-install so this is really my very last option. 
Or downgrade to xp?????

Other info:-

Windows vista

Safe mode works fine am using laptop for this

Its a Toshiba Satellite Pro U500

The question is where do I go from here??

Any help would be very much appreciated

Please let me know if any more info required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a windows 7 Bootable Disc.
You need to do a fresh install of windows 7, make sure your bios is set to load the cd-rom FIRST, during your post, a prompt will ask if you want to boot the disc and to press any key.

Then simply do an upgrade without formatting, and windows 7 will install without overwriting your old data and place all the files in a windows.old directory in your root drive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I've tried this, but its states to upgrade I must run the program from windows when its running. And I can only run windows in safe-mode

Comment: this is false, you should be able to boot from dos as long as your windows 7 disc is `bootable`, If your cd rom is first to boot on the list and nothing happens, your disc is not bootable, and i suggest you do get one, cause it will solve all your problems.

Comment: also where did you get your windows 7 disc from?

Comment: win 7 disk boots from start-up, then gives me option to upgrade or install. Install states its a complete install with format drive etc. choose upgrade and it states to restart with win vista running. From a colleague.

Comment: What do you mean win vista running?

Comment: in my instructions it tells you to do an UPGRADE, and NOT to format. You don't have to do an upgrade from an operating system for this to work.

Comment: It states that to upgrade to win 7, win vista has to be running, can only run win vista in safe-mode and it states that win vista needs to be running correctly.

Comment: From research there seems to be different versions of installation disks? does this make sense?

Comment: Then your disc is not a full installation Disc an Upgrade Disc only. You need to get your hands on a Full installation Disc. Also you can't just barrow a disc from someone that has already used the disc and registered it. The cd key would of already been used.

Comment: ah...ok.. I'm going to take it in somewhere and get the correct disks.

Comment: Does your laptop have a feature where you can just press a key at start up and simply reinstall everything from factory default? Cause if it does, then just remove the hard drive get all your data out of it, and reboot to factory default

Comment: Not that i can see or in manuals

Comment: + that will remove all programs etc anyway wouldn't it?

Comment: check [THIS](http://forums.computers.toshiba-europe.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=50703) out. Yes it will remove all your programs, but normally you can just reinstall them. Read the Last comment.